# The method 'setState' isn't defined for the type 'NasabahDataTableSource'

Tags: flutter, setstate

I want to use setState method in class "NasabahDataTableSource" but when i use setState in this class cannot work and Error: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'NasabahDataTableSource'.

- 'NasabahDataTableSource' is from 'package:flutter_auth/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart' ('lib/screens/Menu/DataNasabah/datanasabah.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setState'.
  setState(() {
  ^^^^^^^^

This is mystatefullwidget.

```
class DataNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataNasabahState createState() => _DataNasabahState();
}

class _DataNasabahState extends State<DataNasabah> {
  String nama_debitur = '';
  List<Nasabah> _nasabah = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadUserData();
    _getNasabah();
  }

  _loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        nama_debitur = user['nama_debitur'];
      });
    }
  }

  _getNasabah() {
    NasabahService.getUser().then((nasabah) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _nasabah = nasabah;
        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Data Nasabah'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff151515),
        // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          rowsPerPage: 10,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'ID Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Nama Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Aksi',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
          ],
          source: NasabahDataTableSource(userData: _nasabah, context: context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use setState method in this class.but cann't use.I
comment setState place

```
class NasabahDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  BuildContext context;
  NasabahDataTableSource({this.context, this.userData});
  final List<Nasabah> userData;

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "${userData[index].id}",
            ))),
        DataCell(Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("${userData[index].nama_debitur}"),
        )),
        DataCell(
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          DetailNasabah(
                            nasabah: userData[index],
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) =>
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Hapus Data Nasabah'),
                          content: Text(
                              'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data nasabah ini?'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                child: Text('Yes'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  NasabahService.deleteUser(userData[index].id);
                                  setState(() {
                                    //Cann't use
                                  });
                                })
                          ],
                        ),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

i haven't find that solution.
Please help.

Comment: What is DataTableSource? Make sure you are using statefull widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `setState()` without `StatefulWidget`. I suggest you to use `Function` to pass your action and notify to rebuild UI using `setState()`. Need little bit modification on your code.

1. Add `Function` parameter to your `NasabahDataTableSource`.

```
Function onUserDeleted;
```

2. Modify your `NasabahDataTableSource` constructor.

```
NasabahDataTableSource({required this.context,required this.userData,required this.onUserDeleted}); // modify your constructor
```

3. Replace `setState` by `onUserDeleted` inside `onPressed`.

```
onUserDeleted(); // call onUserDeleted
//setState(() {
       //Cann't use
//});
```

`NasabahDataTableSource` full code.

```
class NasabahDataTableSource extends DataTableSource {
  BuildContext context;
  Function onUserDeleted; // add onUserDeleted function
  final List<Nasabah> userData;
  NasabahDataTableSource({required this.context,required this.userData,required this.onUserDeleted}); // modify your constructor

  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      index: index,
      cells: [
        DataCell(Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              "${userData[index].id}",
            ))),
        DataCell(Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("${userData[index].nama_debitur}"),
        )),
        DataCell(
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          DetailNasabah(
                            nasabah: userData[index],
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) =>
                        AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Hapus Data Nasabah'),
                          content: Text(
                              'Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data nasabah ini?'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                                child: Text('Yes'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  NasabahService.deleteUser(userData[index].id);
                                  onUserDeleted(); // call onUserDeleted
                                  //setState(() {
                                    //Cann't use
                                  //});
                                })
                          ],
                        ),
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

4. Modify your `DataNasabah` source by adding `onUserDeleted` and call `setState`

```
source: NasabahDataTableSource(
                    userData: _nasabah,
                    context: context,
                    onUserDeleted:(){
                      setState((){}); // add setState
                    }),
```

`DataNasabah` full code.

```
class DataNasabah extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataNasabahState createState() => _DataNasabahState();
}

class _DataNasabahState extends State<DataNasabah> {
  String nama_debitur = '';
  List<Nasabah> _nasabah = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadUserData();
    _getNasabah();
  }

  _loadUserData() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var user = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('user'));

    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        nama_debitur = user['nama_debitur'];
      });
    }
  }

  _getNasabah() {
    NasabahService.getUser().then((nasabah) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _nasabah = nasabah;
        });
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Data Nasabah'),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff151515),
        // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: PaginatedDataTable(
          rowsPerPage: 10,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'ID Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Nama Nasabah',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                'Aksi',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              )),
            ),
          ],
          source: NasabahDataTableSource(
                    userData: _nasabah,
                    context: context,
                    onUserDeleted:(){
                      setState((){}); // add setState
                    }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant setstate in NasabahDataTableSource because not extends StatefulWidget. only stateful who can setstate.
but you can change variable without setstate using getx in stateless.

Comment: class was extend `State<T extends StatefullWidget>` not `StatefulWidget`. and there is a widget call `StatefullBuilder` can call setstate too.

Comment: can you give example this source code ?